# Why is VideoDataOutput's availableVideoCodecTypes empty?

Tags: ios, iphone, codec, avcapture

AVCaptureVideoDataOutput has a field [availableVideoCodecTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutput/1389227-availablevideocodectypes) that's supposed to tell you what codecs you can use to record a video, but it's always empty. Why is this?

I checked its value immediately after creating the VideoDataOutput, and after adding it to the session, but it's empty. I tried on an iPhone 5s running iOS 10, and an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 11, and it's empty on both.

This question is about AVCaptureVideoDataOutput. AVCaptureMovieFileOutput has [another field](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemoviefileoutput/1648381-availablevideocodectypes) with the same name, which works, but the question isn't about that.

One could say that VideoDataOutput gives you the frames rather than recording to a file, so a codec isn't involved, which is why the property is nil, but in that case, why have the property at all?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's empty. I ran into the same problem myself, BUT you can call the following method on AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and get valid results:

```
- (NSArray<AVVideoCodecType> *)availableVideoCodecTypesForAssetWriterWithOutputFileType:(AVFileType)outputFileType;
```

example usage:

```
NSArray *availableVideoCodecTypes = [videoDataOutput availableVideoCodecTypesForAssetWriterWithOutputFileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie];
```

on iPhone XR running iOS 12 this returns

```
hvc1, // AKA HVEC or H.265
avc1, // AKA H.264
jpeg
```

on iPhone 6s+ running iOS 12 it returns

```
avc1, // AKA H.264
jpeg
```